# Icons compressed on main domain

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com/ (or the [http version](https://stackexchange.com/))
2. Open the achievements ([image]) menu at the top at the page
3. Observe the bug:

[image] [image]

If you compare this with the achievements menu at this website, you will see that at this site, the icons are better centered and not touching the line below the entry.

I think this is a bug because it looks poorly touching the gray line, and it does not happen on any other stack site.

This bug does happen on Windows using Google Chrome 48.0.2564.116, with the https version of the website, and not zoomed in (just normal 100%).

Comment: Do you happen to be zoomed in/out?

Comment: No, I am not zoomed in/out, I am just on normal 100% zoom, I edited my google chrome version to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found and removed the offending overriding style.

With you in the next se.com build.

Comment: I can confirm the new styles are active and working at the moment, thx for your time.